# Использование функций MatLab в Visual Studio C#.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

При открытии Add Reference на вкладке COM не могу найти подходящую объектную библиотеку для использования функций MatLab. MatLab установлен.

Comment: Посмотрите это http://habrahabr.ru/post/132487/ , только там для 8-й студии и 10-го матлаба.

Comment: Попробуйте поискать в каталоге `<инсталляция MATLAB>\bin\win32\` или что-то наподобие.